# conflicting functions when using two includes (mybb and wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, mybb

I use MyBB for forum and Wordpress for blog. When I try to integrate both together into a page, I get conflicts between functions. The forum header and the wordpress includes have some functions with the same identifier.

I need both functions but I obviously can't change the name of something inside wordpress or mybb.

What are the solutions to these conflicting problems?

Can I deinclude an included file?

If I could use iframe then it wouldn't look good with the scrolls and the border. If this is the only way then how can I remove the border and the scrollbars so that it would look exactly the same when the code was in the original page itself?

Comment: Switch to libraries that make proper use of namespaces.

Comment: You are essentially trying to merge two of the worst and largest codebases around in PHP. There is no *good* solution, some things simply do not work well together.

Comment: are you actually trying to truely integrate the two (share users table, sessions etc) or just display the forum with your blogs header and footer? The latter is easy enough, the former, not so much.

Comment: what about runkit rename function?I can rename all the functions that conflict before including the second include.

Comment: @YashasSamaga did you find a solution with runkit? consider writing an answer yourself so people who find this on google will profit from it

Answer (score 2):

First of all: That is a hell of a task.
Still thou, if you aim to do it, read up on [namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.namespaces.php).
I figure it is possible to add those to all wordpress classes and all myBB classes.

You would have to do a lot of rewriting, but some search and replace tools using regular expressions should be able to help you with that.

You could also try to havew them seperately (yourdomain.com/myBB and yourdomain.com/wp) and integrate them via webservices. So you myBB would access wordpress data via RSS?

Comment: I imagine i would be easier to write the whole site from scratch than do this with those code bases

Comment: might be. but if he/she just REALLY wants to do it - i won't encourage doing it, but i think it is possible after all.

Comment: what about runkit rename function?

Comment: What about asking a new question concerning that? And what about giving an upvote at least for our effort since our answers are not off track or wrong or anything?